# How do shared budgeting apps like Goodbudget and Honeydue allow different users to access the same information on one account?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an app that's similar to shared budgeting apps like [Homebudget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anishu.homebudget.full&hl=en) or [Honeydue](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.honeydue.honeydue&hl=en), **which allow different app users to share and access the same information on one app account or to at least link their accounts so that they see the same information.**

- Can someone briefly explain, how this feature is added to the app during the development process?
- Is this done in Android Studio, or does it require another form of software?
- Is there a term for this that will point me in the right direction?
- How can an app developer make an app that allows users to link their accounts in order to share and access the same information?

Thanks in advance.